# Python 3 NetScanner Daemon

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, networking, tcp

I’m pretty new to programming and python in particular. This is a simple ICMP/TCP scanner that dumps output to a terminal and/or csv file. My goal was to make a daemon that could do simple scanning without requiring any special imports. It is my first attempt at writing something that would be useful and that I might even cannibalize for other projects. I just finished the TCP scanning portion of it and have done some basic vetting.

Really what I’m looking for specific feedback on is:

**Performance and Efficiency** (I know these terms are ambiguous in code, so I’ll elaborate)

1. Do you see anything that is effectively a memory leak?
2. Do you see anything that can be done with less code and or is
   repeated too many times?
3. Do you see anything that is clearly written badly and needs
   attention (arg structure, looping, etc)
4. Do you see anything that will become less efficient as it loops? I
   haven’t run my script for long durations yet, as most of my time has
   been spent making sure it functions

**Process**

1. Is my code written well?
2. Should I rearrange anything?
3. Am I using the right loops for the right jobs?
4. Are my TCP sockets written well enough?
5. I borrowed the ICMP code, is there a better way to do that?
6. Do you find any of it particularly good/bad/dangerous?

**Format**

1. How does it look?
2. I know the RFC for python formatting, but haven’t read fully through
   it yet. Is there anything that makes your eye twitch?
3. Does what I’ve written look like usable code to you when you look at
   it? (I know this is objective and kind of random, as well as not
   100% related to function, but I really do want this feedback from
   someone who looks at code a lot, if you’re willing to give it).
4. What’s your first reaction when looking at this script?

Other than that I’ll take any feedback you have on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
#==================================================================================#
# AUTHOR: Chris Gleason                                                            #
# DATE:   1/12/2016                                                                #
# Version:  1.0                                                                    #
# COMMENT: NetScan deamon to monitor state changes for network nodes               #
#==================================================================================#
# Simple ICMP/TCP Netscanner to monitor state changes on the network                #
#==================================================================================#

### DESCRIPTION/SYNOPSIS ###

This is a simple daemon that will allow you to scan a network range using ICMP, TCP or UDP and 
store the information in either memory or a file so that it can be referenced at a specific interval
for state changes. It will allow you to log alerts or email them out to a specific email. It will
also, eventually allow you to run it in the background, once I finish up the argparse variables...

### FUTURE WORK ###

1-14-2016 :

I am building this out as a basic ICMP scanner to store up and down states of specific
nodes. I plan to add functions to do TCP and UDP SYN scanning as well as allow for out and in files
to use to store and retrive state data. I also want to add functions for logging and emailing state
alerts. But the first order of business is to get basic ICMP scanning and state alerting to the
console.

2-19-2016 :

- Handle the following Exceptions: 
     * OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host
- Fix --host parameter from changing state if node is up or down. Get initial scan to not count.
- Fix email alerting so that it only sends out a single email per scan round.
- Fix formatting of output table so tabs are lined up.
- Add Validation for things like out and infile locations, IP Format, etc.
- Add argument varaibles so argument values can be passed at runtime and script can be run in the
backround.

4-4-2016 :

Add scan finish statistics, wether it crashes or user kills it with Ctrl+c, output scann settings
Number of times scanned and final version of DB with a close message.

5-7-2016 :

Add a quiet option, so if they actually want to demonize it it will stay quiet and won't dump active
data to the terminal. Then once killed or crashed it will print out the final state dict.

### REQUIREMENTS ###

Requires Python 3 and OSX to run. If you read the script carefully you could redesign for python 2
and for other platforms. The OSX specific subprocess calls and the subnet mask conversion are really
the only platform dependent code.

### NOTES ###

IPAddress module will do a lot of the heavy lifting with regards to calculating subnet nodes using a
CIDR (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html)

Seems like the socket generator has a hard time keeping up if the scanner runs to fast to often. Not
sure if it's flood protection or the TCP stack coming unravelled. I haven't done any packet filtering to
see what's happening at the packet level except to make sure the original scnaner is indeed sending
raw ICMP, but I did find that if I set the time out too low and the scann frequency too low, that
eventually the scanner will halt with a no route to host error. I found the sweet spot is:

timeout > .05 seconds
frequency > 30 seconds

When running with these threshholds the scanner will run continuously with few issues. If you're
scanning larger networks, it may make sense to lower the timeout. I find it works fine at .01 but will
eventually fail if you scann to often, so set the frequency higher if you're scanning large subnets.

'''

__version__ = "$Revision: 1.0"

###########
# IMPORTS #
###########

import argparse
import subprocess
import os
import ipaddress
import sys
import time
import random
import select
import socket
import csv
import threading
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime

###########################################
# NON FUNCTION/CLASS SCRIPT RELATED STUFF #
###########################################

if os.geteuid() != 0:
        exit('''

This program creates and uses raw sockets which require root\n\
priviledges to run. Please run it as root in order to use it.

''')

if sys.platform != 'darwin':
    print ("This script was designed to run on OSX. Currently that is the only platform it will work on.")
    exit(0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='\
    Network scanning daemon to check for node state changes via TCP/UDP/ICMP. \
    Default (no arguments) will run in the foreground using ICMP and broadcast\
    domain for discovery and will store state data in memory. Default (no arguments)\
    uses true ICMP, so it\'s not usually routed. If you "ping scan" with NMAP that rides\
    over TCP unless you specifically tell it to use the ICMP protocol, so if you are\
    trying to scan a remote subnet, use the --tcp flag.')

parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Use TCP SYN/ACK scanning for discovery')
parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Use to demonize netscanner for background processing - NOT IMPLEMENTED YET')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--infile' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Use an existing CSV file instead of scanning the network for initial discovery')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Export stat data to a CSV file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--cidr' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Use a CIDR block to generate scan range instead of using the broadcast domain')
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Monitor the state of a single host')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--email' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Use a gmail account to send state change alerts to a desired email as well as the console')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--logging' ,
    action='store_true' ,
    help='Log state changes to system logs as well as the console')

args = parser.parse_args()
ip = ""
nm = ""
dd_nm = ""
tout = .1
iface = ""
state_dict = {}
freq = ""
count = 0
rtt = ""
ofile = ""
alert_total = ""
totalruns = 0
t1 = datetime.now()

#############
# FUNCTIONS #
#############


def output_title(title):

    '''
    Function to auto-generate output headers and titles

    output=string
    '''

    titlelen = len(title)
    print('=' * titlelen)
    print(title)
    print('=' * titlelen)

def get_tout(a):

    '''
    Function to solicit timeout from the user
    '''

    global tout

    print()
    tout = input('What timeout would you like to use (in seconds and you can use decimal numbers): ')
    print()

    return tout

def get_net_size(netmask):

    '''
    Function that helps convert netmask and IP into CIDR block.
    This code was borrowed. I can tell that it turns the inegerized octet of the Hex NetMask
    into a binary number that is then pumped into zfill and stripped of zeros. How it
    actually converts this into a CIDR block I'm not entirely sure yet. I'll figure it out
    later.
    '''

    binary_str = ''
    for octet in netmask:
        binary_str += bin(int(octet))[2:].zfill(8)
    return str(len(binary_str.rstrip('0')))

def get_net_info():

    '''
    Function that pulls net info from the host converts it into subnet info, calculates hosts
    list and dumps it into an array

    output=strings and a dictionary
    '''

    global ip
    global cidr
    global dd_nm
    global iface
    global tout

    iface = input('What interface would you like to use: ')
    #get_tout(tout)

    # Get IP from subprocess

    ipcmd = "ifconfig %s | grep netmask | awk {'print $2'}" % (iface)
    ip = subprocess.Popen(ipcmd , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ip = ip.stdout.read()
    ip = str(ip).strip('b').strip('\'').strip('\\n')

    # Get Netmask from subprocess

    nmcmd = "ifconfig %s | grep netmask | awk {'print $4'}" % (iface)
    nm = subprocess.Popen(nmcmd , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    nm = nm.stdout.read()
    nm = str(nm).strip('b').strip('\'').strip('\\n')

    # Convert hexmask to dotted decimal

    i = nm
    prefix = i[0:2]
    first = i[2:4]
    second = i[4:6]
    third = i[6:8]
    forth = i[8:10]

    oct1 = "0x{}".format(first)
    oct2 = "0x{}".format(second)
    oct3 = "0x{}".format(third)
    oct4 = "0x{}".format(forth)

    oct1 = int(oct1, 0)
    oct2 = int(oct2, 0)
    oct3 = int(oct3, 0)
    oct4 = int(oct4, 0)

    dd_nm = ("" + str(oct1) + "." + str(oct2) + "." + str(oct3) + "." + str(oct4))
    dd_nm = str(dd_nm)

    # Convert IP and dotted decimal netmask to a CIDR block

    splitip = ip.split('.')
    splitnm = dd_nm.split('.')
    net_start = [str(int(splitip[x]) & int(splitnm[x]))
                 for x in range(0,4)]    
    cidr = str('.'.join(net_start) + '/' + get_net_size(splitnm))

    ### RETURNS ###

    return cidr
    return dd_nm
    return ip
    return iface
    return tout

def print_net_info(a, b, c):

    '''
    Test function to see what is being returned after each stage
    '''

    print ()

    title="NETWORK INFORMATION"
    output_title(title)

    global cidr
    global dd_nm
    global ip

    print ()
    print ("IP is " + b)
    print ("Netmask is " + c)
    print ("CIDR is " + a)

def chk(data):

    '''
    Function that validates data being sent to ping function
    '''

    x = sum(a + b * 256 for a, b in zip(data[::2], data[1::2] + b'\x00')) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    return (~x & 0xFFFF).to_bytes(2, 'little')

def ping(addr, timeout=tout):

    '''
    This Function creates a raw socket using ICMP, then connects to an address
    using that socket, recording the time it takes to return. You can specify
    timeout in the functions arguments. Currently uses user input.
    '''

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) as conn:
        payload = random.randrange(0, 65536).to_bytes(2, 'big') + b'\x01\x00'
        packet  = b'\x08\x00' + b'\x00\x00' + payload
        packet  = b'\x08\x00' + chk(packet) + payload
        conn.connect((addr, 80))
        conn.sendall(packet)

        start = time.time()

        while select.select([conn], [], [], max(0, start + timeout - time.time()))[0]:
            packet    = conn.recv(1024)[20:]
            unchecked = packet[:2] + b'\0\0' + packet[4:]

            if packet == b'\0\0' + chk(unchecked) + payload:
                return time.time() - start


def tcp_scan(addr, port, timeout=tout):

    '''
    Function for scanning with TCP
    '''
    global result

    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    result = s.connect_ex((addr, port))
    #print ('Scanning - ' + addr)
    s.settimeout(None)
    s.close()
    return result


def initial_net_scan(a):

    '''
    Function takes cidr variable from get_net_info, creates a list of IP's
    then scans them all using the ping function
    '''

    global totalruns
    global state_dict

    net4 = ipaddress.ip_network(a)
    print ()
    print ("Calculating network host list and scanning.")
    print ()
    print ("Please be patient, this may take some time:")
    print ()
    if not (args.tcp): # and not (args.udp):
        for x in net4.hosts():
            state_dict.update({x : [ping(str(x), float(tout)), 0]})
    if args.tcp:
        for x in net4.hosts():
            #state_dict.update({x : [0, 0]})
            #for a,b in state_dict.items():
            start = time.time()
            tcp_scan(str(x), int(port), float(tout))
            if result != 0:
                rtt = None
            else:
                rtt = time.time() - start
            state_dict.update({x : [rtt, 0]})


#            start = time.time()
#            tcp_scan(str(host), int(port))
#            if result != 0:
#                rtt2 = None
#            else:
#                rtt2 = time.time() - start


    totalruns += 1

    return totalruns
    return state_dict

def redundant_net_scan(a, host, port):

    '''
    Function takes the state_dict generated from the initial_net_scan function
    then scans the IP's again an calculates if the state has changed
    '''

    global totalruns
    global count
    global state_dict
    global alert_total

    print ("Rescanning, this may take some time:")
    print ()
    alert_total = ""
    for x,y in a.items():
        print_ip = x
        rtt1 = y[0]
        if args.tcp:
            start = time.time()
            tcp_scan(str(x), int(port), float(tout))
            if result != 0:
                rtt2 = None
            else:
                rtt2 = time.time() - start
        else:
            rtt2 = ping(str(x), float(tout))
        count = y[1]
        if type(rtt1).__name__ == "float" and type(rtt2).__name__ == "NoneType"\
        or type(rtt1).__name__ == "NoneType" and type(rtt2).__name__ == "float":
            alert = "State changed for " + str(print_ip) + ". It went from " + str(rtt1) + " to " + str(rtt2) + ".\n"
            alert_total+=alert
            count = y[1] + 1
            state_dict.update({x : [rtt2, count]})
            count = 0
        else:
            state_dict.update({x : [rtt2, count]})

    if args.logging:
        #print(alert_total)
        log_alert(alert_total)

    if args.email:
        email_alert(toaddrs, username, password, alert_total)

    print(alert_total)

    totalruns += 1

    return count
    return state_dict
    return alert_total
    return totalruns

def print_dict(sd):

    '''
    Prints out state dictionary in formatted output
    '''

    global state_dict

    for x,y in sd.items():
        print_ip = x
        print_rtt = y[0]
        print_count = y[1]
        print ("IP: " + str(print_ip) + "\t\tRTT: " + str(print_rtt) + "\t\t\tChange Count: " + str(print_count))

def csv_writer(ofile):

    '''
    Function to take State Dictionary and output to to CSV file
    '''

    writer = csv.writer(open(ofile, 'w'))
    for x,y in state_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([x, y[0], y[1]])

def email_alert(toaddrs, username, password, alerti_total):

    '''
    Function to send state change list to designated email
    '''

    fromaddr = 'netscanalert@chrisgleason.com'
    msg = alert_total
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()

def log_alert(alert):

    '''
    Function to take state change list and log in syslog
    '''

    subprocess.Popen("logger " + alert, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

############
# MAIN RUN #
############


if __name__ == "__main__":

    '''
    Main Code run
    '''


    try:

        title='Netscanner - Network state discovery and change alerter daemon'
        output_title(title)
        print()
        print('Hit Ctrl+C to kill the deamon if it\'s running in the foreground')
        print()

        print()
        freq = input('What frequency would you like the scanner to run (in seconds): ')
        print()

        get_tout(tout)

        if args.tcp: # or args.udp:
            port = input('What port would you like to use to scan against? : ')
            print ()
        else:
            port = 0

        if args.cidr or args.infile or args.host:
            pass
        else:
            get_net_info()

        if args.cidr:
            cidr = input('What CIDR block would you like to use (use X.X.X.X/XXX format) : ')
            #get_tout(tout)
            print ()
            print ('You chose CIDR block: ' + cidr)

        if args.infile:
            ifile = input('Please specify the explicit path to the file you want to import: ')
            reader = csv.reader(open(ifile, 'r'))
            state_dict = {}
            for row in reader:
                ip, rtt, count = row
                if rtt == '':
                    rtt = 'None'
                state_dict[ip] = [rtt, count]

        if args.outfile:
            ofile = input('Please specify the explicit path to the file you want to export the data to: ')

        if args.host:
            global host
            host = input('What host would you like to scan (Use an IP in dotted decimal format X.X.X.X): ')
            if not (args.tcp): # and not (args.udp):
                rtt = ping(str(host), float(tout))
                state_dict.update({host : [rtt, count]})
            if args.tcp:
                start = time.time()
                tcp_scan(str(host), int(port))
                if result != 0:
                   rtt = None
                else:
                   rtt = time.time() - start
                state_dict.update({host : [rtt, count]})
            cidr = host + "/32"
        else:
            host = '0.0.0.0'

        if args.email:
            toaddrs  = input('What email are you sending alerts to: ')
            username = input('What is your gmail username: ')
            password = input('What is your gmail password (you may need an application specific password): ')

        if args.cidr or args.infile:
            pass
        else:
            print_net_info(cidr, ip, dd_nm)

        print ()
        input('Press Enter to start the scan')
        if not args.infile:
            os.system('clear')
            initial_net_scan(cidr)
            print_dict(state_dict)
            if args.outfile:
                csv_writer(ofile)
            time.sleep(int(freq))

        while True:
            os.system('clear')
            redundant_net_scan(state_dict, host, port)
            print_dict(state_dict)
            if args.outfile:
                csv_writer(ofile)
            time.sleep(int(freq))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print ()
        print ("===================================================================================")
        print ()
        print_dict(state_dict)
        print ()
        print ("===================================================================================")
        print ()
        print ("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        print ()
        print ("Your scan ran through " + str(totalruns) + " cycles, every " + str(freq) + " seconds.")
        print ()
        print ("The scan ran for a total of " + str(timetotal))
        print ()
        print ("The final data set is above:")
        sys.exit()

    except OSError as e:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print ()
        print ('Script crashed')
        print ('Dumping state dict')
        print ()
        print ('====================================================================================')
        print ()
        print_dict(state_dict)
        print ()
        print ('====================================================================================')
        print ()
        print ('There was an OS Error exception, most likely a no route to host. for now, I\'m just')
        print ('dumping the last version of the state dictionary and exiting.')
        print ()
        print ("Your scan ran through " + str(totalruns) + " cycles, every " + str(freq) + " seconds.")
        print ()
        print ("The scan ran for a total of " + str(timetotal))
        print ()
        print ('If you\'re seeing this error a lot, try changing the frequency to at least 30 seconds, and')
        print ('set the timeout to at least .1 for a trial. If it stops, you can tune it down. If it keeps')
        print ('failing, then you should increase both thresholds until it stops')
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why people think this may have generated zero comments? Did my phrasing turn people off? Is the code so terrible you don't even want to get involved? Did something I said in a previous submission make ppl upset? I've had quite a time trying to get feedback on this in a few places, so I'm wondering if it's something tangible?

Comment: Might have been a mix between lack of views, and long code. Also keep in mind that Code Review has a [fairly small active community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python/topusers), and so if even one of the active users misses this or turns this question down, it's _much_ more likely to be unanswered than if we were say SO.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I'll try to comment on this code as much as I can, but due to the fact that you said:

> Requires Python 3 and **OSX to run**.

*Note that this could also be the reason some users don't review your code (I kinda like running the code that I edit, so that I can be sure it really brings some improvements)*

I won't be able to run / test it. I'll start from the top to the bottom.

### Formatting:

#### Imports

- don't import modules if you're not using them (e.g: `import threading` )

Try to also put them in an alphabetically order:

```
import argparse
import csv
import ipaddress
import os
import random
import select
import smtplib
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
```

#### Punctuation

-in Python, we don't put a <kbd>space</kbd> before a comma:

```
 parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp' ,
        action='store_true' ,
        help='Use TCP SYN/ACK scanning for discovery')
```

should become:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use TCP SYN/ACK scanning for discovery')
```

*Please also note the new alignment that I've made. This way, your code become more readable.*

#### Comments

I personally don't like:

```
###########################################
# NON FUNCTION/CLASS SCRIPT RELATED STUFF #
###########################################
```

Because it's distracting me + you shouldn't make obvious comments. In this case, it's obviously what you're doing. However, if you want to be sure that every person who'll step into this code will understand it, just:

```
# Non function / class related stuff
```

More,

> triple double-quoted strings should be used for docstrings (but that's debatable - just told you so you'll know).

This means that:

```
def output_title(title):

    '''
    Function to auto-generate output headers and titles

    output=string
    '''
```

might become:

```
def output_title(title):
    # Function to auto-generate output headers and titles(output=string)
    '''
```

#### Spacing

Between methods, you should have two blank lines, not one:

```
def output_title(title):
    ....


def get_tout(a):
    ....
```

I kinda' see a `perl`ish thing when you:

```
payload = random.randrange(0, 65536).to_bytes(2, 'big') + b'\x01\x00'
packet  = b'\x08\x00' + b'\x00\x00' + payload
packet  = b'\x08\x00' + chk(packet) + payload
```

You have multiple spaces before operator, and that's not ok according to PEP8. So, this will become:

```
payload = random.randrange(0, 65536).to_bytes(2, 'big') + b'\x01\x00'
packet = b'\x08\x00' + b'\x00\x00' + payload
packet = b'\x08\x00' + chk(packet) + payload
```

#### Parentheses

You can remove redundant parentheses:

```
if not (args.tcp):
    ....
```

should be:

```
if not args.tcp:
    ....
```

To sum up all that I said so far, your code would look like this (if you want to respect [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

```
import argparse
import csv
import ipaddress
import os
import random
import select
import smtplib
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Non function / class related stuff

if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit('''

This program creates and uses raw sockets which require root\n\
priviledges to run. Please run it as root in order to use it.

''')

if sys.platform != 'darwin':
    print("This script was designed to run on OSX. Currently that is the only platform it will work on.")
    exit(0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='\
    Network scanning daemon to check for node state changes via TCP/UDP/ICMP. \
    Default (no arguments) will run in the foreground using ICMP and broadcast\
    domain for discovery and will store state data in memory. Default (no arguments)\
    uses true ICMP, so it\'s not usually routed. If you "ping scan" with NMAP that rides\
    over TCP unless you specifically tell it to use the ICMP protocol, so if you are\
    trying to scan a remote subnet, use the --tcp flag.')

parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use TCP SYN/ACK scanning for discovery')
parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use to demonize netscanner for background processing - NOT IMPLEMENTED YET')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--infile',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use an existing CSV file instead of scanning the network for initial discovery')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Export stat data to a CSV file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--cidr',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use a CIDR block to generate scan range instead of using the broadcast domain')
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Monitor the state of a single host')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--email',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Use a gmail account to send state change alerts to a desired email as well as the console')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--logging',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Log state changes to system logs as well as the console')

args = parser.parse_args()
ip = ""
nm = ""
dd_nm = ""
tout = .1
iface = ""
state_dict = {}
freq = ""
count = 0
rtt = ""
ofile = ""
alert_total = ""
totalruns = 0
t1 = datetime.now()


# Functions


def output_title(title):
    # Function to auto-generate output headers and titles(output=string)

    titlelen = len(title)
    print('=' * titlelen)
    print(title)
    print('=' * titlelen)


def get_tout(a):
    # Function to solicit timeout from the user

    global tout

    print()
    tout = input('What timeout would you like to use (in seconds and you can use decimal numbers): ')
    print()

    return tout


def get_net_size(netmask):
    '''
    Function that helps convert netmask and IP into CIDR block.
    This code was borrowed. I can tell that it turns the inegerized octet of the Hex NetMask
    into a binary number that is then pumped into zfill and stripped of zeros. How it
    actually converts this into a CIDR block I'm not entirely sure yet. I'll figure it out
    later.
    '''

    binary_str = ''
    for octet in netmask:
        binary_str += bin(int(octet))[2:].zfill(8)
    return str(len(binary_str.rstrip('0')))


def get_net_info():
    '''
    Function that pulls net info from the host converts it into subnet info, calculates hosts
    list and dumps it into an array

    output=strings and a dictionary
    '''

    global ip
    global cidr
    global dd_nm
    global iface
    global tout

    iface = input('What interface would you like to use: ')
    # get_tout(tout)

    # Get IP from subprocess

    ipcmd = "ifconfig %s | grep netmask | awk {'print $2'}" % (iface)
    ip = subprocess.Popen(ipcmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ip = ip.stdout.read()
    ip = str(ip).strip('b').strip('\'').strip('\\n')

    # Get Netmask from subprocess

    nmcmd = "ifconfig %s | grep netmask | awk {'print $4'}" % (iface)
    nm = subprocess.Popen(nmcmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    nm = nm.stdout.read()
    nm = str(nm).strip('b').strip('\'').strip('\\n')

    # Convert hexmask to dotted decimal

    i = nm
    prefix = i[0:2]
    first = i[2:4]
    second = i[4:6]
    third = i[6:8]
    forth = i[8:10]

    oct1 = "0x{}".format(first)
    oct2 = "0x{}".format(second)
    oct3 = "0x{}".format(third)
    oct4 = "0x{}".format(forth)

    oct1 = int(oct1, 0)
    oct2 = int(oct2, 0)
    oct3 = int(oct3, 0)
    oct4 = int(oct4, 0)

    dd_nm = ("" + str(oct1) + "." + str(oct2) + "." + str(oct3) + "." + str(oct4))
    dd_nm = str(dd_nm)

    # Convert IP and dotted decimal netmask to a CIDR block

    splitip = ip.split('.')
    splitnm = dd_nm.split('.')
    net_start = [str(int(splitip[x]) & int(splitnm[x]))
                 for x in range(0, 4)]
    cidr = str('.'.join(net_start) + '/' + get_net_size(splitnm))

    return cidr
    return dd_nm
    return ip
    return iface
    return tout


def print_net_info(a, b, c):
    # Test function to see what is being returned after each stage

    print()
    title = "NETWORK INFORMATION"
    output_title(title)

    global cidr
    global dd_nm
    global ip

    print()
    print("IP is " + b)
    print("Netmask is " + c)
    print("CIDR is " + a)


def chk(data):
    # Function that validates data being sent to ping function

    x = sum(a + b * 256 for a, b in zip(data[::2], data[1::2] + b'\x00')) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    return (~x & 0xFFFF).to_bytes(2, 'little')


def ping(addr, timeout=tout):
    '''
    This Function creates a raw socket using ICMP, then connects to an address
    using that socket, recording the time it takes to return. You can specify
    timeout in the functions arguments. Currently uses user input.
    '''

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) as conn:
        payload = random.randrange(0, 65536).to_bytes(2, 'big') + b'\x01\x00'
        packet = b'\x08\x00' + b'\x00\x00' + payload
        packet = b'\x08\x00' + chk(packet) + payload
        conn.connect((addr, 80))
        conn.sendall(packet)

        start = time.time()

        while select.select([conn], [], [], max(0, start + timeout - time.time()))[0]:
            packet = conn.recv(1024)[20:]
            unchecked = packet[:2] + b'\0\0' + packet[4:]

            if packet == b'\0\0' + chk(unchecked) + payload:
                return time.time() - start


def tcp_scan(addr, port, timeout=tout):
    # Function for scanning with TCP

    global result

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    result = s.connect_ex((addr, port))
    # print ('Scanning - ' + addr)
    s.settimeout(None)
    s.close()
    return result


def initial_net_scan(a):
    '''
    Function takes cidr variable from get_net_info, creates a list of IP's
    then scans them all using the ping function
    '''

    global totalruns
    global state_dict

    net4 = ipaddress.ip_network(a)
    print()
    print("Calculating network host list and scanning.")
    print()
    print("Please be patient, this may take some time:")
    print()
    if not (args.tcp):  # and not (args.udp):
        for x in net4.hosts():
            state_dict.update({x: [ping(str(x), float(tout)), 0]})
    if args.tcp:
        for x in net4.hosts():
            # state_dict.update({x : [0, 0]})
            # for a,b in state_dict.items():
            start = time.time()
            tcp_scan(str(x), int(port), float(tout))
            if result != 0:
                rtt = None
            else:
                rtt = time.time() - start
            state_dict.update({x: [rtt, 0]})

    totalruns += 1

    return totalruns
    return state_dict


def redundant_net_scan(a, host, port):
    '''
    Function takes the state_dict generated from the initial_net_scan function
    then scans the IP's again an calculates if the state has changed
    '''

    global totalruns
    global count
    global state_dict
    global alert_total

    print("Rescanning, this may take some time:")
    print()
    alert_total = ""
    for x, y in a.items():
        print_ip = x
        rtt1 = y[0]
        if args.tcp:
            start = time.time()
            tcp_scan(str(x), int(port), float(tout))
            if result != 0:
                rtt2 = None
            else:
                rtt2 = time.time() - start
        else:
            rtt2 = ping(str(x), float(tout))
        count = y[1]
        if type(rtt1).__name__ == "float" and type(rtt2).__name__ == "NoneType" \
                or type(rtt1).__name__ == "NoneType" and type(rtt2).__name__ == "float":
            alert = "State changed for " + str(print_ip) + ". It went from " + str(rtt1) + " to " + str(rtt2) + ".\n"
            alert_total += alert
            count = y[1] + 1
            state_dict.update({x: [rtt2, count]})
            count = 0
        else:
            state_dict.update({x: [rtt2, count]})

    if args.logging:
        # print(alert_total)
        log_alert(alert_total)

    if args.email:
        email_alert(toaddrs, username, password, alert_total)

    print(alert_total)

    totalruns += 1

    return count
    return state_dict
    return alert_total
    return totalruns


def print_dict(sd):
    # Prints out state dictionary in formatted output

    global state_dict

    for x, y in sd.items():
        print_ip = x
        print_rtt = y[0]
        print_count = y[1]
        print("IP: " + str(print_ip) + "\t\tRTT: " + str(print_rtt) + "\t\t\tChange Count: " + str(print_count))


def csv_writer(ofile):
    # Function to take State Dictionary and output to to CSV file

    writer = csv.writer(open(ofile, 'w'))
    for x, y in state_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([x, y[0], y[1]])


def email_alert(toaddrs, username, password, alerti_total):
    # Function to send state change list to designated email

    fromaddr = 'netscanalert@chrisgleason.com'
    msg = alert_total
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()


def log_alert(alert):
    # Function to take state change list and log in syslog

    subprocess.Popen("logger " + alert, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:

        title = 'Netscanner - Network state discovery and change alerter daemon'
        output_title(title)
        print()
        print('Hit Ctrl+C to kill the deamon if it\'s running in the foreground')
        print()

        print()
        freq = input('What frequency would you like the scanner to run (in seconds): ')
        print()

        get_tout(tout)

        if args.tcp:  # or args.udp:
            port = input('What port would you like to use to scan against? : ')
            print()
        else:
            port = 0

        if args.cidr or args.infile or args.host:
            pass
        else:
            get_net_info()

        if args.cidr:
            cidr = input('What CIDR block would you like to use (use X.X.X.X/XXX format) : ')
            # get_tout(tout)
            print()
            print('You chose CIDR block: ' + cidr)

        if args.infile:
            ifile = input('Please specify the explicit path to the file you want to import: ')
            reader = csv.reader(open(ifile, 'r'))
            state_dict = {}
            for row in reader:
                ip, rtt, count = row
                if rtt == '':
                    rtt = 'None'
                state_dict[ip] = [rtt, count]

        if args.outfile:
            ofile = input('Please specify the explicit path to the file you want to export the data to: ')

        if args.host:
            global host
            host = input('What host would you like to scan (Use an IP in dotted decimal format X.X.X.X): ')
            if not (args.tcp):  # and not (args.udp):
                rtt = ping(str(host), float(tout))
                state_dict.update({host: [rtt, count]})
            if args.tcp:
                start = time.time()
                tcp_scan(str(host), int(port))
                if result != 0:
                    rtt = None
                else:
                    rtt = time.time() - start
                state_dict.update({host: [rtt, count]})
            cidr = host + "/32"
        else:
            host = '0.0.0.0'

        if args.email:
            toaddrs = input('What email are you sending alerts to: ')
            username = input('What is your gmail username: ')
            password = input('What is your gmail password (you may need an application specific password): ')

        if args.cidr or args.infile:
            pass
        else:
            print_net_info(cidr, ip, dd_nm)

        print()
        input('Press Enter to start the scan')
        if not args.infile:
            os.system('clear')
            initial_net_scan(cidr)
            print_dict(state_dict)
            if args.outfile:
                csv_writer(ofile)
            time.sleep(int(freq))

        while True:
            os.system('clear')
            redundant_net_scan(state_dict, host, port)
            print_dict(state_dict)
            if args.outfile:
                csv_writer(ofile)
            time.sleep(int(freq))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print()
        print("===================================================================================")
        print()
        print_dict(state_dict)
        print()
        print("===================================================================================")
        print()
        print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        print()
        print("Your scan ran through " + str(totalruns) + " cycles, every " + str(freq) + " seconds.")
        print()
        print("The scan ran for a total of " + str(timetotal))
        print()
        print("The final data set is above:")
        sys.exit()

    except OSError as e:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print()
        print('Script crashed')
        print('Dumping state dict')
        print()
        print('====================================================================================')
        print()
        print_dict(state_dict)
        print()
        print('====================================================================================')
        print()
        print('There was an OS Error exception, most likely a no route to host. for now, I\'m just')
        print('dumping the last version of the state dictionary and exiting.')
        print()
        print("Your scan ran through " + str(totalruns) + " cycles, every " + str(freq) + " seconds.")
        print()
        print("The scan ran for a total of " + str(timetotal))
        print()
        print('If you\'re seeing this error a lot, try changing the frequency to at least 30 seconds, and')
        print('set the timeout to at least .1 for a trial. If it stops, you can tune it down. If it keeps')
        print('failing, then you should increase both thresholds until it stops')
```

### Some more digging into the code

**Don't you ever**, ever, use multiple `return`s in a single method. It's just not possible:

```
return count
return state_dict
return alert_total
return totalruns
```

I don't know how your code would run because the last three `return`s are unreachable. You might try:

```
return count, state,dict, alert_total, total_runs
```

In some of your methods, you're passing some arguments that you never use, so get rid of them as it make the code inconsistent:

```
def get_tout(a): # in this case, you never use the argument so you can get rid of it.
```

#### Globals

Try to avoid using globals as much as possible. Global variables should be avoided because they inhibit code reuse. The reason they are bad is that they allow functions to have hidden (as in "non-obvious" and "undeclared") and thus hard to understand side effects. Also, this can lead to [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

I'll add more when I will have the time ^^

Comment: Thanks Dex' ter for the thorough answer. I'll go through it in the next day or so, been very busy with work.

Answer (score 4):

#### Baseline quality

As you say this project is near to your heart. I suggest to try the PyCharm IDE, community edition. It has a built-in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) validator and will give you many warnings on coding style, which you will want to fix to make this project as good as it can be. It helps you in many other ways too, for example it tells you about unused imports and variables, variables shadowing global scope, easy renaming of variables and functions, and many others.

Alternatively, you can install the PEP8 command line tool with `pip install pep8`, and there other analyzers too like `pyflakes` and `pylint`.

If you're serious about the project, use serious tools, and move basic quality issues out of the way.

#### Code organization

It would be good to move all code in the global scope into a `main` function. That way the main functionality can be imported by other packages.
Even if you don't intend to make the core functionality reusable now,
this practice will help building good habits,
and help eliminating global variables.

Note that code inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` is also in global scope, and should be moved as well. The problem is that any variables you declare will be visible in all methods. This can be really confusing and lead to programming errors.

By moving all code into functions, variables will not be visible inside your functions "by accident", and the dependencies and inputs of every function will become clearer.

#### Number conversion

This is a bit dirty and unnecessarily complicated:

> ```
> oct1 = "0x{}".format(first)
> oct1 = int(oct1, 0)
> ```

This is straightforward and natural:

```
oct1 = int(first, 16)
```

#### Unnecessary conversions

The 2nd line here is unnecessary, the first line already makes `dd_nm` a string:

> ```
> dd_nm = ("" + str(oct1) + "." + str(oct2) + "." + str(oct3) + "." + str(oct4))
> dd_nm = str(dd_nm)
> ```

#### Error reporting

Consider this:

> ```
> print ('There was an OS Error exception, most likely a no route to host. for now, I\'m just')
> print ('dumping the last version of the state dictionary and exiting.')
> ```

It's probably a good idea to include the exact error that happened:

```
print(e)
```

#### Formatting

In many places you used `'...'.format(...)`, but in many places you didn't, for example:

> ```
> print ("Your scan ran through " + str(totalruns) + " cycles, every " + str(freq) + " seconds.")
> ```

It would better and simpler to use `format` consistently everywhere.

```
print("Your scan ran through {} cycles, every {} seconds.".format(totalruns, freq))
```

---

It's a minor thing, but the text output doesn't fit within 80 characters,
a common width for terminals.
For a command line tool it's good to stick within that width.

---

Early in the program you printed a multiline string using a `'''` block,
but later inside functions you used multiple `print(...)` statements.
I suspect you wanted to avoid strange indentation like this:

```
    except OSError as e:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print("""
Script crashed
Dumping state dict
""")
```

A common workaround for that is using `textwrap.dedent` like this:

```
    except OSError as e:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        timetotal = t2 - t1
        print(textwrap.dedent("""
            Script crashed
            Dumping state dict
            """))
```

---

You print a long line of `=` at many places.
What if you decide to change the width?
You will probably want to make that change everywhere, which can be a pain.
Avoid this kind of duplication by moving that to a function, for example:

```
def print_sep():
    print('====================================================================================')
```

And, instead of typing a long line of `=`, you can type an exact count easily:

```
def print_sep():
    print('=' * 80)
```

#### Naming

Consider this function:

> ```
> def print_net_info(a, b, c):
>
>     '''
>     Test function to see what is being returned after each stage
>     '''
>
>     print ()
>
>     title="NETWORK INFORMATION"
>     output_title(title)
>
>     global cidr
>     global dd_nm
>     global ip
>
>     print ()
>     print ("IP is " + b)
>     print ("Netmask is " + c)
>     print ("CIDR is " + a)
> ```

Why not drop the unused `global` variables and rename a, b, c naturally to ip, netmark and cidr?

Comment: Nice answer. As you're suggesting a lot of tools, have you tried [Prospector](https://prospector.readthedocs.io/en/master/supported_tools.html)? It seems to include all the linters you've suggested.

Comment: @JoeWallis I think I've heard of it (probably from your comments on other pots). Thanks for the tip, will check it out!

Comment: Thanks Janos for the thorough answer. Is PEP8 something that established python writers just can't forgive if it's not adhered to strictly? I guess I'm asking if most people just take a quick look to see if it's formatted correctly first and if not, just dismiss it as not mature code? I get the value behind it for sure. I'll run this through pycharm in the next day or so and validate it myself, as well as go through the rest of your comments.

Comment: Hi @ChrisGleason, you're welcome. I hope to find time to add some more. Your code is long, and I think more can be said. And yes, PEP8 is important. It's more than just coding style tips, I suggest to read the full document, as it's full of examples of *pythonic thinking*. You don't have to correct strictly everything 100%, but at least try to converge to it, and definitely clear out the easily fixable violations.